# Optimizing Distributed I/O with serial output

Tags: openmdao

I am having trouble understanding how to optimize a distributed component with a serial output. This is my attempt with an example problem given in the openmdao docs.

```python
import numpy as np

import openmdao.api as om
from openmdao.utils.array_utils import evenly_distrib_idxs
from openmdao.utils.mpi import MPI


class MixedDistrib2(om.ExplicitComponent):

    def setup(self):
        # Distributed Input
        self.add_input('in_dist', shape_by_conn=True, distributed=True)
        # Serial Input
        self.add_input('in_serial', val=1)
        # Distributed Output
        self.add_output('out_dist', copy_shape='in_dist', distributed=True)
        # Serial Output
        self.add_output('out_serial', copy_shape='in_serial')
        #self.declare_partials('*','*', method='cs')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        x = inputs['in_dist']
        y = inputs['in_serial']
        # "Computationally Intensive" operation that we wish to parallelize.
        f_x = x**2 - 2.0*x + 4.0
        # These operations are repeated on all procs.
        f_y = y ** 0.5
        g_y = y**2 + 3.0*y - 5.0
        # Compute square root of our portion of the distributed input.
        g_x = x ** 0.5
        # Distributed output
        outputs['out_dist'] = f_x + f_y
        # Serial output
        if MPI and comm.size > 1:
            # We need to gather the summed values to compute the total sum over all procs.
            local_sum = np.array(np.sum(g_x))
            total_sum = local_sum.copy()
            self.comm.Allreduce(local_sum, total_sum, op=MPI.SUM)
            outputs['out_serial'] = g_y * total_sum
        else:
            # Recommended to make sure your code can run in serial too, for testing.
            outputs['out_serial'] = g_y * np.sum(g_x)

size = 7
if MPI:
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    rank = comm.rank
    sizes, offsets = evenly_distrib_idxs(comm.size, size)
else:
    # When running in serial, the entire variable is on rank 0.
    rank = 0
    sizes = {rank : size}
    offsets = {rank : 0}

prob = om.Problem()
model = prob.model

# Create a distributed source for the distributed input.
ivc = om.IndepVarComp()
ivc.add_output('x_dist', np.zeros(sizes[rank]), distributed=True)
ivc.add_output('x_serial', val=1)

model.add_subsystem("indep", ivc)
model.add_subsystem("D1", MixedDistrib2())
model.add_subsystem('con_cmp1', om.ExecComp('con1 = y**2'), promotes=['con1', 'y'])

model.connect('indep.x_dist', 'D1.in_dist')
model.connect('indep.x_serial', ['D1.in_serial','y'])

prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

model.add_design_var('indep.x_serial', lower=5, upper=10)
model.add_constraint('con1', upper=90)

model.add_objective('D1.out_serial')

prob.setup(force_alloc_complex=True)
#prob.setup()

# Set initial values of distributed variable.
x_dist_init = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
prob.set_val('indep.x_dist', x_dist_init)

# Set initial values of serial variable.
prob.set_val('indep.x_serial', 10)

#prob.run_model()

prob.run_driver()
print('x_dist', prob.get_val('indep.x_dist', get_remote=True))
print('x_serial', prob.get_val('indep.x_serial'))
print('Obj', prob.get_val('D1.out_serial'))
```

The problem is with defining partials with 'fd' or 'cs'. I cannot define partials of serial output w.r.t distributed input. So I used `prob.setup(force_alloc_complex=True)` to use complex step. But gives me this warning `DerivativesWarning:Constraints or objectives [('D1.out_serial', inds=[0])] cannot be impacted by the design variables of the problem.` I understand this is because the total derivative is 0 which causes the warning but I dont understand the reason. Clearly the total derivative should not be 0 here. But I guess this is because I didn't explicitly `declare_partials` in the component. I tried removing the distributed components and ran it again with `declare_partials` and this works correctly(code below).

```Python
import numpy as np

import openmdao.api as om


class MixedDistrib2(om.ExplicitComponent):

    def setup(self):

        self.add_input('in_dist', np.zeros(7))
        self.add_input('in_serial', val=1)

        self.add_output('out_serial', val=0)
        self.declare_partials('*','*', method='cs')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        x = inputs['in_dist']
        y = inputs['in_serial']

        g_y = y**2 + 3.0*y - 5.0
        g_x = x ** 0.5

        outputs['out_serial'] = g_y * np.sum(g_x)    

prob = om.Problem()
model = prob.model

model.add_subsystem("D1", MixedDistrib2(), promotes_inputs=['in_dist', 'in_serial'], promotes_outputs=['out_serial'])
model.add_subsystem('con_cmp1', om.ExecComp('con1 = in_serial**2'), promotes=['con1', 'in_serial'])

prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

model.add_design_var('in_serial', lower=5, upper=10)
model.add_constraint('con1', upper=90)

model.add_objective('out_serial')

prob.setup(force_alloc_complex=True)

prob.set_val('in_dist', [1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
prob.set_val('in_serial', 10)

prob.run_model()
prob.check_totals()

prob.run_driver()

print('x_dist', prob.get_val('in_dist', get_remote=True))
print('x_serial', prob.get_val('in_serial'))
print('Obj', prob.get_val('out_serial'))
```

What I am trying to understand is

1. How to use 'fd' or 'cs' in Distributed component with a serial output?
2. What is the meaning of `prob.setup(force_alloc_complex=True)` ? Is not forcing to use  cs in all the components in the problem ? If so why does the total derivative becomes 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code in OpenMDAO V 3.11.0 (after uncommenting the `declare_partials` call) I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: 'D1' <class MixedDistrib2>: component has defined partial ('out_serial', 'in_dist') which is a serial output wrt a distributed input. This is only supported using the matrix free API.
```

As the error indicates, you can't use the matrix-based api for derivatives in this situations. The reasons why are a bit subtle, and probably outside the scope of what needs to be delt with to answer your question here. It boils down to OpenMDAO not knowing why kind of distributed operations are being done in the compute and having no way to manage those details when you propagate things in reverse.

So you need to use the [matrix-free derivative APIs](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.11.0/features/core_features/working_with_components/explicit_component.html) in this situation. When you use the matrix-free APIs you **DO NOT** declare any partials, because you don't want OpenMDAO to allocate any memory for you to store partials in (and you wouldn't use that memory even if it did).

I've coded them for your example here, but I need to note a few important details:

1. Your example has a distributed IVC, but as of OpenMDAO V3.11.0 you can't get total derivatives with respect to distributed design variables. I assume you just made it that way to make your simple test case, but in case your real problem was set up this way, you need to note this and not do it this way. Instead, make the IVC serial, and use src indices to distribute the correct parts to each proc.
2. In the example below, the derivatives are correct. However, there seems to be a bug in the check_partials output when running in paralle. So the reverse mode partials look like they are off by a factor of the comm size... this will have to get fixed in later releases.
3. I only did the derivatives for `out_serial`. `out_dist` will work similarly and is left as an excersize for the reader :)
4. You'll notice that I duplicates some code in the `compute` and `compute_jacvec_product` methods. You can abstract this duplicate code out into its own method (or call `compute` from within `compute_jacvec_product` by providing your own output dictionary). However, you might be asking why the duplicate call is needed at all? Why can't u store the values from the compute call. The answer is, in large part, that OpenMDAO does not guarantee that `compute` is always called before `compute_jacvec_product`. However, I'll also point out that this kind of code duplication is very AD-like. Any AD code will have the same kind of duplication built in, even though you don't see it.

```
import numpy as np

import openmdao.api as om
from openmdao.utils.array_utils import evenly_distrib_idxs
from openmdao.utils.mpi import MPI


class MixedDistrib2(om.ExplicitComponent):

    def setup(self):
        # Distributed Input
        self.add_input('in_dist', shape_by_conn=True, distributed=True)
        # Serial Input
        self.add_input('in_serial', val=1)
        # Distributed Output
        self.add_output('out_dist', copy_shape='in_dist', distributed=True)
        # Serial Output
        self.add_output('out_serial', copy_shape='in_serial')

        # self.declare_partials('*','*', method='fd')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        x = inputs['in_dist']
        y = inputs['in_serial']
        # "Computationally Intensive" operation that we wish to parallelize.
        f_x = x**2 - 2.0*x + 4.0 
        # These operations are repeated on all procs.
        f_y = y ** 0.5
        g_y = y**2 + 3.0*y - 5.0
        # Compute square root of our portion of the distributed input.
        g_x = x ** 0.5
        # Distributed output
        outputs['out_dist'] = f_x + f_y
        # Serial output
        if MPI and comm.size > 1:
            # We need to gather the summed values to compute the total sum over all procs.
            local_sum = np.array(np.sum(g_x))
            total_sum = local_sum.copy()
            self.comm.Allreduce(local_sum, total_sum, op=MPI.SUM)
            outputs['out_serial'] = g_y * total_sum
        else:
            # Recommended to make sure your code can run in serial too, for testing.
            outputs['out_serial'] = g_y * np.sum(g_x)


    def compute_jacvec_product(self, inputs, d_inputs, d_outputs, mode):

        x = inputs['in_dist']
        y = inputs['in_serial']

        g_y = y**2 + 3.0*y - 5.0

        # "Computationally Intensive" operation that we wish to parallelize.
        f_x = x**2 - 2.0*x + 4.0 
        # These operations are repeated on all procs.
        f_y = y ** 0.5
        g_y = y**2 + 3.0*y - 5.0
        # Compute square root of our portion of the distributed input.
        g_x = x ** 0.5
        # Distributed output
        out_dist = f_x + f_y

        # Serial output
        if MPI and comm.size > 1:
            # We need to gather the summed values to compute the total sum over all procs.
            local_sum = np.array(np.sum(g_x))
            total_sum = local_sum.copy()
            self.comm.Allreduce(local_sum, total_sum, op=MPI.SUM)
            # total_sum
        else:
            # Recommended to make sure your code can run in serial too, for testing.
            total_sum = np.sum(g_x)

        num_x = len(x)

        d_f_x__d_x = np.diag(2*x - 2.)
        d_f_y__d_y = np.ones(num_x)*0.5*y**-0.5

        d_g_y__d_y = 2*y + 3.
        d_g_x__d_x = 0.5*x**-0.5

        d_out_dist__d_x =  d_f_x__d_x # square matrix
        d_out_dist__d_y =  d_f_y__d_y # num_x,1

        d_out_serial__d_y =  d_g_y__d_y # scalar
        d_out_serial__d_x =  g_y*d_g_x__d_x.reshape((1,num_x))

        if mode == 'fwd':
            if 'out_serial' in d_outputs:
                if 'in_dist' in d_inputs:
                    d_outputs['out_serial'] += d_out_serial__d_x.dot(d_inputs['in_dist'])
                if 'in_serial' in d_inputs:
                    d_outputs['out_serial'] += d_out_serial__d_y.dot(d_inputs['in_serial'])
        elif mode == 'rev':
            if 'out_serial' in d_outputs:
                if 'in_dist' in d_inputs:
                    d_inputs['in_dist'] += d_out_serial__d_x.T.dot(d_outputs['out_serial'])
                if 'in_serial' in d_inputs:
                    d_inputs['in_serial'] += total_sum*d_out_serial__d_y.T.dot(d_outputs['out_serial'])

size = 7
if MPI:
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    rank = comm.rank
    sizes, offsets = evenly_distrib_idxs(comm.size, size)
else:
    # When running in serial, the entire variable is on rank 0.
    rank = 0
    sizes = {rank : size}
    offsets = {rank : 0}

prob = om.Problem()
model = prob.model

# Create a distributed source for the distributed input.
ivc = om.IndepVarComp()
ivc.add_output('x_dist', np.zeros(sizes[rank]), distributed=True)
ivc.add_output('x_serial', val=1)

model.add_subsystem("indep", ivc)
model.add_subsystem("D1", MixedDistrib2())
model.add_subsystem('con_cmp1', om.ExecComp('con1 = y**2'), promotes=['con1', 'y'])

model.connect('indep.x_dist', 'D1.in_dist')
model.connect('indep.x_serial', ['D1.in_serial','y'])

prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

model.add_design_var('indep.x_serial', lower=5, upper=10)
model.add_constraint('con1', upper=90)

model.add_objective('D1.out_serial')

prob.setup(force_alloc_complex=True)
#prob.setup()

# Set initial values of distributed variable.
x_dist_init = np.ones(sizes[rank])
prob.set_val('indep.x_dist', x_dist_init)

# Set initial values of serial variable.
prob.set_val('indep.x_serial', 10)

prob.run_model()

prob.check_partials()

# prob.run_driver()
print('x_dist', prob.get_val('indep.x_dist', get_remote=True))
print('x_serial', prob.get_val('indep.x_serial'))
print('Obj', prob.get_val('D1.out_serial'))
```